# mongodb - aggregate failed with memory error

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to find duplicates in my sharded collection using the id field, which is of this pattern -

```
"id" : {
        "idInner" : {
            "k1" : "v1",
            "k2" : "v2",
            "k3" : "v3",
            "k4" : "v4"
        }
}
```

I used the below query, but received the "exception: Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in." error, even though I used "allowDiskUse : true" in my query.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: {
    _id: { id: "$id" },
    uniqueIds: { $addToSet: "$_id" },
    count: { $sum: 1 } 
  } }, 
  { $match: { 
    count: { $gte: 2 } 
  } },
  { $sort : { count : -1} },
  { $limit : 10 }
], 
{ 
    allowDiskUse : true
});
```

Is there another way to get what I want, or something else I should pass in the above query? Thanks.

Comment: The `_id` field itself is always indexed with a "unique" constraint. It **cannot** contain duplicates.

Comment: This is not the "_id" field, which in my case I'm letting mongo populate by default. I have my own "id" (without the underscore) which contains my key.

Comment: Do you really need the `uniqueIds: { $addToSet: "$_id" }` in your group? that might alleviate some of the memory problem.

Comment: I have about 2M docs in my collection. Commenting out the 'uniqueIds: { $addToSet: "$_id" }' as well as using the '_id: "$id.idInner"' still comes back with the same error.

Comment: if you want unique data in your collection based on your own "id", I'll suggest create unique index on it. This is most efficient way to ensure unique documents in collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use allowDiskTrue in run command.

```
db.runCommand(
   { aggregate: "collection",
     pipeline: [
  { $group: {
    _id: { id: "$id" },
    uniqueIds: { $addToSet: "$_id" },
    count: { $sum: 1 } 
  } }, 
  { $match: { 
    count: { $gte: 2 } 
  } },
  { $sort : { count : -1} },
  { $limit : 10 }
],
     allowDiskUse: true
   }
)
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Sorry, but I just gave this a try, and it worked great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Run a `$match` first in the pipeline to keep only  documents of let's say `id.idiInner.k1` that are between a range, so that you will take results for that range only. Since you are interested in duplicates on the `id` key, all the duplicated documents will satisfy this criteria. See how much you should narrow down that range and run it next for the next range etc. until you cover all documents.

If it is something you must do frequently, automate, by declaring the ranges, feed them in a loop, keep the duplicates of every run and merge the results in the end.

Another fast hack/trick would be to bypass the **mongos** and run the aggregation directly in each **shard**. Doing so will limit your docs roughly (assuming well balanced shards) to docs/number_of_shards and you may overcome the memory limit. In this second approach I assume that your shard key is the id key, however if it is not then this approach will not work since the same duplicated documents will be scattered among the shards.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting using the $match to narrow down the results. This helped me get what I want.